# How to store a single selected row value in variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

entry in row "cars" is "BMWx1"

```
  $sql = "SELECT cars FROM table LIMIT 1";

        $result = $con->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $rows[] = $result->fetch_row();
            $result->free();
        }
echo json_encode($rows[0]);
```

output: `["BMWx1"]`

So far so good. Now how do I get my variable $cars to be equal to "BMWx1"

e.g.:

```
  echo $cars; 
  output: BMWx1
```

Thanks you

Comment: `$cars = $rows[0][0]`. But why are you making `$rows` an array if you're just fetching one row?

Comment: because I am sitting on this problem  for 3 hours now , reading myself trough tons of tutorials, just to get a single selected row value stored in a variable. I just entangled myself into this... if you use the answer button, I would gladly accept your answer.  If you can provide a best practice, i would be even more glad. Thank you

Comment: as @Barmar said you shouldn't use `$rows` trying doing it with http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php it will be more effective and simple to deal with.

Comment: Forget about tutorials, think about it logically. If you need multiple rows, use an array. If you need a single row, just use a normal variable. Programming requires logical thinking, not copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just reading a single row, don't push the row onto an array. `fetch_assoc` returns an associative array containing the row that was retrieved from the query (or `false` if there was nothing selected). Just use that and access the column you want.

```
$result = $con->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row) {
    $cars = $row['cars'];
}
```